# I need help completing this program

Tags: c++

These are the requirements for my program. Code a program that will find the minimum, maximum, and sum of two integers and of three integers.  Use 1 overloaded function for each of min, max, & sum. I have gotten most of it done, but dont know how to add an overload function. here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

   int num1, num2;

   cout<<"Enter first number: ";

   cin>>num1;

   cout<<"Enter second number: ";
   cin>>num2;
   cout<<"Sum of " << num1<< " and " <<num2<<"  is: "<<(num1+num2)<<endl;

   if (num1>num2)
   {
   cout << "The max is " << num1<< " and the min is " << num2<< endl;
   }
   else
   {
       cout<< num2 << " is the max, and " <<num1 <<" is the min"<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think overload means to implement `int min(int, int)`, `int min(int, int, int)`, and likewise for `max` and `sum`

Comment: Exactly! I was about to write that :) An overloaded function has different implementation with the same name but a different combination of formal parameters, thus you can have something like what @BradyDean proposed, and every call to the function is named the same. No need to have eg. min2 and min3 different names. Also, you can have it overloaded with different types like this: min(float, float), but now they are asking just integers. BTW: You are not creating yet any function but main in your code... Do you need help on how to write a function?

Comment: So where would i incorporate that in my code? I'm just confused where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to separate the code into functions, and more specifically, to two different functions, with the same **name**, but with a different **parameters** (this means that this function has a different ***signature***, and this is how the compiler distinguish one function to another!).

The code should look like that:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int add(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int max(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return max(a, max(b, c));
}
```

Notice the little "trick" (which is recommended), that I have used the 2-argument `max` in the 3-argument `max`, instead of re-implement the same logic twice. In this way, if you have a bug, you will have a bug in both, but if you fix it, it will be fixed in both at the same time. This is true for many other type of functions!

Also, denote the `(expression) ? (value_1) : (value_2)` which is a short version for `if` assignment, which can be used when assigning variables **or** when returning a value, and are in common use.

***P.S*** you can make in such a way an overload for any number of arguments, and for any type that has the `operator<` (although it does contain a problem, if the arguments are not from the same type!), using:

```
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
T max(T a, Ts... others)
{
    const T max_of_others = max(others...);
    return (a > max_of_others) ? a : max_of_others;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "max of 1-6 is: " << max(1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

But it is an overkill here! (just good to know for the future!)

Comment: @SarahBaig Glad to help! If it closes this thread, please, except the answer (using the V symbol)